# When should you use a sub join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Check the following code:

```
    declare @A table (Id int, b_Id int)
    declare @B table (Id int, c_Id int)
    declare @C table (Id int)

    insert into @A values(1, 10)
    insert into @A values(2, 11)
    insert into @A values(3, null)

    insert into @B values(10, 100)
    insert into @B values(11, null)
    insert into @B values(12, 101)

    insert into @C values(100)
    insert into @C values(101)
    insert into @C values(102)
```

Query 1)

```
    Select 
        a.Id, b.Id, c.Id 
    from 
        @A a 
        Left join @B b on a.B_Id = b.Id
        join @C c on b.C_Id = c.Id
```

Query 2)

```
    Select 
        a.Id, b.Id, c.Id 
    from 
        @A a 
        Left join @B b on a.B_Id = b.Id
        Left join @C c on b.C_Id = c.Id
```

Query 3)

```
    Select 
        a.Id, b.Id, c.Id 
    from 
        @A a 
        Left join @B b
            join @C c on b.C_Id = c.Id  
         on a.B_Id = b.Id
```

This results in this:
The first query

```
1   10  100
```

the second query:

```
 1  10  100
 2  11  NULL
 3  NULL    NULL
```

The third query:

```
1   10  100
2   NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL
```

Now I would like to know when do you use the third query where the on statement of b is after the on statement of c in the query. 
And how can one rewrite this in order to get the same results.

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name. Also your question is not that clear.

Comment: question has been edited, hopefully its better clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third query is highly non-standard:

```
select a.Id, b.Id, c.Id 
from @A a left join
     @B b join
     @C c
     on b.C_Id = c.Id  
     on a.B_Id = b.Id;
```

It makes more sense if you write this using parentheses:

```
select a.Id, b.Id, c.Id 
from @A a left join
     (@B b join
      @C c
      on b.C_Id = c.Id 
     ) 
     on a.B_Id = b.Id;
```

You can rewrite this using `right join`:

```
select a.Id, b.Id, c.Id 
from @B b join
     @C c
     on b.C_Id = c.Id right join
     @A a 
     on a.B_Id = b.Id;
```

In practice, though, I would probably use a subquery:

```
select a.Id, bc.b_Id, bc.c_Id 
from @A a left join
     (select b.Id as b_id, c.Id as c_id
      from @B b join
           @C c
           on b.C_Id = c.Id  
     ) bc
     on a.B_Id = bc.b_Id;
```

I find that this best captures the intention of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some script like below-

```
SELECT A.a_id,
CASE WHEN (A.b_id IS NOT NULL) AND (A.c_id IS NOT NULL) THEN A.b_id END b_id,
CASE WHEN (A.b_id IS NOT NULL) AND (A.c_id IS NOT NULL) THEN A.c_id END c_id
FROM
(
    SELECT A.Id a_id,B.Id b_id,C.Id c_id 
    FROM @A A
    LEFT JOIN @B B  ON A.b_Id = B.Id
    LEFT JOIN @C C ON B.c_Id = C.Id
)A
```